# Facebook API - Accessing a users album and using a photo

Tags: php, api, facebook, file-upload, fbml

If extended permissions have been granted to the app to access a users albums, is it at all possible to display a selector where the user can choose one of their photos and then upload that photo to my website via a form submission?

Answer (score 0):

To upload a file via a form submission, you need a `<input type="file"/>` tag in your multipart form. If you want to display a selector where the user can choose one of their photos, you cant use file inputs or multipart forms. Hovewer, you can use facebook graph api to get users albums and photos. I tried to describe it [here](http://feridcelik.wordpress.com/2010/10/07/accesing-user-photos-via-facebook-graph-api/). Take a look at.